# Page is not loading after deploying the react app in the vercel

Tags: reactjs, web, webpack, vercel

I recently deployed my react app in vercel. My app has web pack confgurations init.
Here is the webpack.config.js file,

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './source/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'index_bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/dist"),
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "react-dom": "@hot-loader/react-dom",
        },
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                    },
                    {
                        loader: path.resolve('loader.js'),
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: {
                    filename: 'images/[name][ext]',
                    publicPath: '/',
                },
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'public/index.html',
            favicon: 'public/favicon.ico',
            manifest: "public/manifest.json"
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        open: true,
        host: 'localhost',
        historyApiFallback: true,
        hot: true,
        server: 'https'
    }
};
```

Here is package.json file,

```
{
  "name": "consent-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --compress --https --port 3000 --mode development",
    "build": "rimraf ../dist/ && webpack --mode production"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "description": "Consent approval web application.",
  "main": "configs.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/pavadaran/consent-approval-ui.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/pavadaran/consent-approval-ui/issues"
  }
  
}
```

Here is the config.js file,

```
import ObDefaultConsent from "./source/src/pages/consentPages/ObDefaultConsent.jsx";
import Oauth2AuthzDisplayConsent from "./source/src/pages/consentPages/Oauth2AuthzDisplayConsent.jsx";
import Oauth2AuthzConfirm from "./source/src/pages/consentPages/Oauth2AuthzConfirm.jsx";
import FourOhFour from "./source/src/pages/errorPages/FourOhFour.jsx";

export const getConfigs = (consentType) => {
  return {
    consentPages: [
      {
        index: 1,
        Component: consentType==="accounts"? ObDefaultConsent:FourOhFour,
      },
      {
        index: 2,
        Component: Oauth2AuthzDisplayConsent,
      },
      {
        index: 3,
        Component: Oauth2AuthzConfirm,
      }
    ],
  };

  /* if(consentType==="accounts"){
    return {
      consentPages: [
        {
          index: 1,
          Component: ObDefaultConsent,
        },
        {
          index: 2,
          Component: Oauth2AuthzConfirm,
        }
      ],
    };
  } else if(consentType==="payments"){
    return {
      consentPages: [
        {
          index: 1,
          Component: ObDefaultConsent,
        },
        {
          index: 2,
          Component: Oauth2AuthzConfirm,
        }
      ],
    };
  } */
};
```

It successfully build with the `npm run build` command. But when I check the vercel deployment the page is not appears and only loads a blank page. This is the link for deployement: https://consent-approval-ui.vercel.app/

I tried with setting a homepage in package.json as "./" , "public/dist" but it's also not worked. Checked the console in the deployement page and it shows some errors.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for chrome-extension://cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb/browser-polyfill.js.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```